# (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) HTTP load failed Error on Ios9 Device

Tags: objective-c, http, parse-platform, ios9

I'm gettin HTTP load failed error which code (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802) on ios9 device from parse.com servers.

I'm pretty sure don't need to disable ATS for parse.com connection and also other api calls are functional.

The error comes from only the code below.

```
    [_answerOwnerUser saveInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(answerOwnerUserSaved:error:)];
```

Called method above and,
`answerOwnerUserSaved` **is not even called.**

Could you please highlight my fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS 9, TLS 1.2 is enforced. If you're not using it, your requests will fail.

Check out [this post](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) for more info.

Here is a temporary workaround until you're ready to adopt iOS9 ATS support:
Right click on your Info.plist file > Open As > Source Code, and add the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
<dict>  
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>  
   <true/>  
</dict>
```